# How to use the resetStyle method in leaflet.js for circle markers that have a dynamic style

Tags: javascript, html, maps, leaflet, mapbox

I tried to do a modification of Leaflet's [chloropeth](http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth.html) tutorial. In the tutorial, hover events trigger setStyle() and resetStyle() methods.

I've tried to do the same thing with click events but it has to work a little differently. Here's what I was trying to accomplish: I wanted to bring in points via geoJSON and turn those into a layer composed of circleMarkers. I wanted to change the fillColor of those circleMarkers to green or yellow depending on whether or not the geoJSON point contained the property: URL. Then I wanted a click event to change the fill color of the target to white so that the user knows which circle is clicked.  Then I wanted a click on any other circle to reset the style to the original green/yellow scheme so that it doesn't just turn every circle white.

I'm not sure how to correctly implement resetStyle() so that it actually resets the entire layer. I keep getting errors on the style function.

These are my click listeners:

```
function clickToControl(e) {
    reset60Day(e);
    layer.setStyle({fillColor: "white"});
    info.update(e.target);
}

//reset
function reset60Day(e) {
  day60Layer.resetStyle(day60Layer);
```

Here's how I implemented the geoJSON layer and styled the points into circle markers:

Style code:

```
var day60Layer = L.geoJson(day60, {
  style: day60Style,
  onEachFeature: onEach60day,
  pointToLayer: function(feature,latlng){
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, null);
  }
});

function day60Style(feature) {
  return {
    radius: 10,
    fillColor: getColor(feature),
    color:"black",
    weight: 2,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity: 0.5
  };

}

//getcolor function
function getColor(feature){
  var url = feature.properties.URL;
  return url ? "green" : "yellow";
  console.log("getcolor fired");

}
```

I eventually got [a version working](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/fracing-ca/index.html), but I had to use a different way altogether.  I eschewed resetStyle() and just used different implementations of setStyle(). In most cases, I think that's a perfectly fine way to do it, but in this case I would be unable to run setStyle() on the fillColor because the fillColor is determined by a function that runs in the style options.  Is there a way to implement resetStyle() for clicks similarly to the leaflet.js Chloropeth example?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you use `L.Util.setOptions(feature,{fallback:url})` inside `getColor(feature)` to set a "fallback" color for each feature,then use

```
day60Layer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
   layer.setStyle({fillColor: layer.options.fallback})
})
```

for your "reset" action?